# Object1's Property has Object1

Tags: java, oop, object

Is this bad practice?

Object1 is an instantiated version of Object.

Object1 has a property called "Example2" which is also an object. The Example2 object has an Object and that object is Object1.

E.g.

```
Example2 example = new Example2(this);
```

Where this is stored as an Object variable.

I'm sorry if I'm not explaining myself. This has made it really hard to google.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a complete code sample. In general - as always - "it depends".

Comment: No, this is quite common. A sub-component holding the reference of the main component isn't bad practice. Sometimes in MVC, sub-controllers do hold the reference of the main/parent controller.

Comment: @daniu I would love to provide a code sample, but I'm currently planning and as such don't have any.

Comment: You can provide a UML class diagram here as well

Comment: *"I'm sorry if I'm not explaining myself. This has made it really hard to google."*  - It is also making it impossible to produce a meaningful answer.  If you can't explain yourself clearly, or provide an example, how are we supposed to know what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad practice in general, but I would consider it a code smell worth looking into. My reasoning for this is that it sounds like it might break separation of concerns: your Example class clearly needs something from the class referred to by `this`, eg

```
class MyService {
    private Controller controller;

    public MyService() {
        controller = new MyController(this);
    }
}
```

A controller having a reference to a service is common, but the other way around much less so.

I'm sure there are valid examples, but I'd say a cyclic reference is not usually a good sign.